# Laço "for" contado número ímpar, par e tirando a média

Tags: java, algoritmo, loop, matemática

Preciso fazer um código que:

- Liste uma quantidade de números
- Informe se são divisíveis por 3 e 5
- Se são pares ou ímpares
- E depois tirar a média separada de cada um (média de ímpares e média de pares)

Elaborei um código, porém quando ele vai realizar o cálculo da média, está dando erro.

Segue código:

```
public class Exe_04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de numeros a serem listados.");
        int cp = ler.nextInt();

        float mediaPar, mediaImpar;
        int contPar = 0, contImpar = 0;

        int num[] = new int[cp];

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite o " + (i + 1) + "° numero: \n");
            num[i] = ler.nextInt();

            if ((num[i] % 3 == 0) && (num[i] % 5 == 0)) {
                System.out.println("Este numero é divisivel por 3 e 5.");
            }
            if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Este numero é PAR.");
                contPar++;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Este numero é IMPAR.");
                contImpar++;
            }

        }
        mediaPar = contPar / num[cp];
        mediaImpar = contImpar / num[cp];

        System.out.println("A media dos numeros PARES é : " + mediaPar);
        System.out.println("A media dos numeros IMPARES é : " + mediaImpar);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para calcular a média precisa achar o total e isto não estava sendo feito, estava dividindo por algo sem sentido.

Também melhorei algumas, por exemplo eliminei o vetor que não estava sendo usado de fato.

Tem outros problemas neste código, mas para um exercício não está ruim, só não ache que este é um bom código para uso em produção em aplicação séria.

Fui baseado no enunciado, pode ter erros aí.

```
import java.util.*;

class Exe_04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de numeros a serem listados.");
        int cp = ler.nextInt();
        int contPar = 0, contImpar = 0;
        int somaPar = 0, somaImpar = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cp; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite o " + (i + 1) + "° numero: \n");
            int num = ler.nextInt();
            if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Este numero é divisivel por 3 e 5.");
            }
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Este numero é PAR.");
                contPar++;
                somaPar += num;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Este numero é IMPAR.");
                contImpar++;
                somaImpar += num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("A media dos numeros PARES é : " + (float)somaPar / contPar);
        System.out.println("A media dos numeros IMPARES é : " + (float)somaImpar / contImpar);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4ZNKMd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zehezina-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Medium.java).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero pela ajuda no código e pelas dicas, sou novo em java ainda, mas vou melhorar mais minha sintax e lógica.

Comment: @WillGreco veja a melhor forma de dizer obrigado no [tour].