# Par ou impar por loop não apresenta o resultado esperado

Tags: java, algoritmo, tipagem

```
public class ParImpar {

public int totali;
public int totalp;

public ParImpar(int totali, int totalp) {
    this.totali = totali;
    this.totalp = totalp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ParImpar(0,1).parImpar();
    //System.out.println(new ParImpar(0, 1).totalp);
}

public void parImpar(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) != 0){
            totali = totali + i;
            System.out.println(totalp);
        }else{
            totalp = totalp * i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total pares " + totalp);
    System.out.println("Total impar " + totali);
}}
```

O meu `totalp` é sempre impresso a 0, já tentei de outras formas e acaba sempre por dar erro.

Comment: Já fez o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) do seu código? Tentou [debugá-lo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/112052)? Na primeira iteração do `for`, o valor de `i` é zero, e ao fazer `totalp = totalp * i`, o valor de `totalp` se torna zero. A partir daí, qualquer outra multiplicação (`totalp = totalp * i`) resultará em zero...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Laço "for" contado número ímpar, par e tirando a média](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242752/la%c3%a7o-for-contado-n%c3%bamero-%c3%admpar-par-e-tirando-a-m%c3%a9dia)

Comment: @hkotsubo sim, mas também tentei iniciar a propriedade a 1 e mesmo assim o resultado foi o mesmo

Comment: Não importa o valor inicial, o problema é que na primeira iteração do `for`, o valor de `i` é zero, e aí `totalp` passa a ser zero. E qualquer outra multiplicação feita depois resultará em zero... Sugiro que siga os links acima (teste de mesa e debug) e tente aplicar ao seu código, e verá com mais clareza o que está acontecendo...

Comment: @RaulOliveira não é o mesmo problema, editei, jájá posto a solução

Comment: @hkotsubo o problema não é esse, parecia mesmo ser.

Comment: @Maniero Fiz um teste rápido e parecia ser só isso mesmo. Mas se vc diz que é outra coisa, vou aguardar sua resposta :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo pode mostrar funcionando?

Comment: @Maniero É, me equivoquei no meu teste rápido - talvez tenha sido rápido demais - e não me atentei para a possibilidade do overflow... Vc tem razão, o `for` começando em zero é só parte do problema...

Comment: @hkotsubo nós dois :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que essa multiplicação que adota um padrão fatorial gerará um número muito grande, muito mesmo. Não cabe em um `int`, ou mesmo um `long`, precisa de um [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) para dar certo, aí fica esse código lindo. Com um `int` o valor rapidamente estoura o limite, e não dá erro por questões de performance, aí o número que deveria ser mais que 2 bilhões se torna negativo (é assim que funciona mesmo, ele inverte o sinal por causa do estouro), e sendo negativo todo o cálculo passa ser errado.

Além disto não poderia começar o `for` com 0, afinal a multiplicação por 0 será 0, e todos os resultados serão contaminados, tem que começar com 1.

```
import java.math.*;

class ParImpar {
    public BigInteger totali;
    public BigInteger totalp;
    public ParImpar(BigInteger totali, BigInteger totalp) {
        this.totali = totali;
        this.totalp = totalp;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ParImpar(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE).parImpar();
    }
    public void parImpar() {
        for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(100)) != 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (i.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0) totali = totali.add(i);
            else totalp = totalp.multiply(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Total pares " + totalp);
        System.out.println("Total impar " + totali);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QzJUIR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MultiplyBigInteger). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/MultiplyBigInteger.java).

Fazer uma classe só para fazer isto acho uma construção bem ruim.

Comment: sim, atribuir valores às propriedades da maneira que fez, também é má prática. Obrigado

Comment: Onde diz que é? E por que? E o que isto quer dizer? Para que serve esse má prática? Sem saber essas coisas não serve pra nada.

Comment: para que serve a má prática? A má prática não server para nada, não deve é ser aplicada! já agora, o seu código dá o mesmo erro que o meu.
`public int totali = 0;
 public int totalp = 1;`
é redundante porque vai ter que atribuir o valor a essas variáveis no psvm

Comment: Sim, eu editei a resposta e logo posto a solução.